# Programmatically centering text in Android's Textview

Tags: android, user-interface, textview, center, centering

I've created a class which extends Android's Text view.  I'm trying to to center the text horizontally and vertically.  The text appears to center horizontally but not vertically.

I've tried both:

```
setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

and

```
setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
```

My class is below:

```
public class NumberView extends TextView
{
  private Paint circlePaint;
  private int radius;

public NumberView(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    setText("0");
    circlePaint = new Paint();
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

//        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0xf1, 0xf1, 0xf1));

    setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 15);

}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // draw circle at center of canvas
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();
    radius = Math.min(width, height);
    radius /= 2;
    canvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, radius, circlePaint);

    //super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

I'm adding NumberView as part of a ExpandableList View.  Down below is how I had the expandable list view to the layout:

```
    listView = new ExpandableListView(this);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    TextView emptyView = new TextView(this);

    listView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
    mainLayout.addView(listView,
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT , 2));
```

Comment: Why aren't you doing this in an XML layout file?

Comment: Long story short, I can't.

Comment: where you are adding NumberView textview to layout please share relevant part of code

Comment: you are creating your custom textview so  Change above code

TextView emptyView = new TextView(this);

to
NumberView numberView=new NumberView(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView emptyView = new TextView(this);
```

Change this to

```
NumberView numberView=new NumberView(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use your NumberView class which you have made instead of TextView 
It will work and you have to set params on your NumberView too.